Custom docker container IP on macOS with Colima
I have the following docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.7'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:16.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: app
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "127.42.90.84:5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
    db:

I'm trying to use Colima with colima start --network-address, but can't reach the service from my local machine with the IP 127.42.90.84 - and I have honestly no idea why.
docker-compose ps: database-1   postgres:16.3     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   database   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes             127.42.90.84:5432->5432/tcp which should be correct
Anyone got an idea? Thanks

You should either remove the IP from the ports section in your docker compose file so it becomes 5432:5432 or run colima status to check the IP address of Colima and specify that IP instead.

I don't want to remove the IP - we've got many projects that use these kind of setup in order to prevent port collisions.

What is 127.42.90.84 ? How did you get it ?

It's just an arbitrary IP address. We've used this approach for quite some time now to give projects different IPs (mostly formatted like 127.something.with.projectid). This works without any issues on Linux and with Docker Desktop (as long as you bind the IP address via sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.xx.xx.xx netmask 0xff000000) - but I can't get it to work on MacOS.

The feature has now been added to Colima https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/492#issuecomment-2264657556.

Just tested this; I still can't reach these custom ips ("Took too long to respond"). Also tried starting with --network-address, but didn't change anything.

The feature was later moved behind a flag and disabled by default and you now need to specify --network-host-addresses.
It also requires network address disabled, so --network-address=false may be required if it was previously enabled.
